# PostgreSQL pivot on dynamic column

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, transpose

I have the following code

```sql
SELECT 
    mu.id,
    u.pk AS fkgerente,
    u.u AS gerente,
    mu.meta,
    mu.meta_date::TEXT
FROM
    usuario u
RIGHT JOIN 
    metas_usuario mu ON mu.user_id = u.pk
JOIN
    metas_type mt ON mt.id = mu.meta_type_id 
WHERE 
    u.del = 0
    AND u.fkp = '2453ff2c-6494-4a6d-a15f-f70384b669c1'
    AND mu.meta_date  BETWEEN SYMMETRIC '2022-08-27' AND '2022-09-24'
    AND mt.id = 4
ORDER BY 
    gerente ASC
```

I get an output like this

[image]

I was wondering if there's anyway to use PIVOT to transpose dynamic columns such as dates (meta_date) to columns to have an output like this:

[image]

When the data is handled by the API server before writing it into the database it ensures it follows some specific rules on how to write meta_date so there will be always date to group on.

I wonder whether is possible to achieve this only using SQL or is it necessary to transpose it on the API.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has crosstab function that you can pivot your data in desired format. Read here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

But there is a sticky limitation here: output (pivoted) columns must be given explicitly . Because sql engine must know output format completely with data types.

Possibly you can write a function that first execute query and  determine output format than create sql dynamically and execute